# Plot an inverse function

Tags: plotting

I have a phrase that in it x is a function of y but I need to plot y as a function of x. I tried InverseFunction but because my phrase is not single-valued in some points Mathematica can not give me a plot. After that, I tried `ParametricPlot` but this code has not any answer. In fact I wanna inverse `x` and `y` axes. what should I do?

```
0.008 y + 
 125. (2. - 
    0.0000271476 (659.714/(1 - 0.169673 y) + (
       2 (2.30388*10^-6 + 0.169673 y)^2)/(1 - 0.169673 y)^2) - (
    0.00271476 (2.30388*10^-6 + 0.169673 y))/(1 - 0.169673 y))^2 y=x 

Plot[{0.008 y + 
 125. (2. - 
    0.0000271476 (659.714/(1 - 0.169673 y) + (
       2 (2.30388*10^-6 + 0.169673 y)^2)/(1 - 0.169673 y)^2) - (
    0.00271476 (2.30388*10^-6 + 0.169673 y))/(1 - 0.169673 y))^2 y}, {y, 5.6, 6}]
```

Comment: I change the coefficients in my code:          `Plot[2.3864*10^-15 y + 
 9.5456*10^-15 (25. - 
    2.78813*10^-9 (659.714/(1 - 5.57627*10^-9 y) + (
       2 (9.21551*10^-6 + 1.39407*10^-6 y)^2)/(1 - 
         5.57627*10^-9 y)^2) - (
    1.39407*10^-6 (9.21551*10^-6 + 1.39407*10^-6 y))/(
    1 - 5.57627*10^-9 y))^2 y, {y, 1.7*10^8, 1.9*10^8}]`        when I plotted these function no minus region appear but when I plotted inverse function with ParametricPlot some region that are minus in sign will appear, why is that?

Answer (score 5):

```
f[y_] := 0.008 y + 
   125. (2. - 
       0.0000271476 (659.714/(1 - 
             0.169673 y) + (2 (2.30388*10^-6 + 0.169673 y)^2)/(1 - 
              0.169673 y)^2) - (0.00271476 (2.30388*10^-6 + 
            0.169673 y))/(1 - 0.169673 y))^2 y;
fun = Plot[f[y], {y, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AspectRatio -> 1];
invfun = ParametricPlot[{f[y], y}, {y, 0, 6}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
GraphicsRow[{fun, invfun}]
```

[image]

Comment: `ContourPlot` is another way.

Comment: I change the coefficients in my code: Plot[2.3864*10^-15 y +   9.5456*10^-15 (25. -      2.78813*10^-9 (659.714/(1 - 5.57627*10^-9 y) + (        2 (9.21551*10^-6 + 1.39407*10^-6 y)^2)/(1 -           5.57627*10^-9 y)^2) - (     1.39407*10^-6 (9.21551*10^-6 + 1.39407*10^-6 y))/(     1 - 5.57627*10^-9 y))^2 y, {y, 1.7*10^8, 1.9*10^8}] when I plotted these function no minus region appear but when I plotted inverse function with `ParametricPlot` some region that are minus in sign will appear, why is that?

Comment: @nafisgh  Since MMA change  the origin automatic. you can set `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}` etc.